# Error on SQL request with INSERT INTO

Tags: javascript, php, sql, symfony

I have an error when I try to put data into my database from my controller with a form inside that take a text. I checked every variable and none of them is null. So when I submit my form, I get this error :

```
SyntaxErrorException: An exception occurred while executing 'INSERT INTO message (message, vu, from, date, type, id_player) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)' with params ["ds", 0, "jean3", "2017-05-05 18:04:39", "message", 7]:
```

And I don't see why my typage could be wrong, it is supposed to be (String, boolean, String, datetime, String, int). And the int is a foreign key, so I set the ID and the entity int my controller for this last row (setIdPlayer and setPlayer ).

Here is my controller :

```js
public function carteAction(Request $request)
    {


        $player = $this->container->get("security.token_storage")->getToken()->getUser();
        $message = new Message;
        //dump($player->getCharacters());
        

        $form = $this->createFormBuilder($message)
            ->add('message', TextareaType::class, array('label' => 'Message :'))
            ->add('registration', SubmitType::class, array('label' => 'Envoie du message'))
            ->getForm();

        $form->handleRequest($request);

        if($form->isSubmitted() && $form->isValid())
        {
            if($request->query->has('to'))
            {
                dump("sending...");
                $message->setMessage($form['message']->getData());
                $message->setFrom($player->getUsername());
                $message->setVu(false);
                $message->setDate(date_create());
                $message->setType("message");
                $to = $this->getDoctrine()->getRepository('AppBundle:Player')
                            ->findByPseudo($request->query->get('to'))[0];
                $id_to = $to->getId();
                dump($id_to);
                dump($to);
                $message->setIdPlayer($id_to);
                $message->setPlayer($to);
                
                //TODO : get to depuis la database et lui foutre le message
                $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
                $em->persist($message); // prépare l'insertion dans la BD
                $em->flush();
            }
            


        }
       
    }
```

Then my Message entity :

```js
<?php

namespace AppBundle\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
 * Message
 *
 * @ORM\Table(name="message")
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="AppBundle\Repository\MessageRepository")
 */
class Message
{
    /**
     * @var int
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="message", type="text")
     */
    private $message;

    /**
     * @var bool
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="vu", type="boolean")
     */
    private $vu;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="from", type="string")
     */
    private $from;

    /**
     * @var \DateTime
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="date", type="datetime")
     */
    private $date;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="type", type="string", length=255)
     */
    private $type;

    /**
     * @var int
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Player", inversedBy="messages")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="id_player", referencedColumnName="id")
     */
    private $player;

    /**
     * @var int
     * @ORM\Column(name="id_player", type="integer")
     */
    private $idPlayer;

    /**
     * Get id
     *
     * @return int
     */
    public function getId()
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

    /**
     * Set message
     *
     * @param string $message
     *
     * @return Message
     */
    public function setMessage($message)
    {
        $this->message = $message;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get message
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getMessage()
    {
        return $this->message;
    }

    /**
     * Set from
     *
     * @param string $from
     *
     * @return Message
     */
    public function setFrom($from)
    {
        $this->from = $from;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get from
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getFrom()
    {
        return $this->from;
    }

    /**
     * Set vu
     *
     * @param boolean $vu
     *
     * @return Message
     */
    public function setVu($vu)
    {
        $this->vu = $vu;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get vu
     *
     * @return bool
     */
    public function getVu()
    {
        return $this->vu;
    }

    /**
     * Set date
     *
     * @param \DateTime $date
     *
     * @return Message
     */
    public function setDate($date)
    {
        $this->date = $date;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get date
     *
     * @return \DateTime
     */
    public function getDate()
    {
        return $this->date;
    }

    /**
     * Set type
     *
     * @param string $type
     *
     * @return Message
     */
    public function setType($type)
    {
        $this->type = $type;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get type
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getType()
    {
        return $this->type;
    }

    /**
     * Set player
     *
     * @param \AppBundle\Entity\Player $player
     *
     * @return Message
     */
    public function setPlayer(\AppBundle\Entity\Player $player = null)
    {
        $this->player = $player;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get player
     *
     * @return \AppBundle\Entity\Player
     */
    public function getPlayer()
    {
        return $this->player;
    }

    /**
     * Set idPlayer
     *
     * @param int $idPlayer
     *
     * @return Message
     */
    public function setIdPlayer($idPlayer)
    {
        $this->idPlayer = $idPlayer;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get idPlayer
     *
     * @return int
     */
    public function getIdPlayer()
    {
        return $this->idPlayer;
    }
}
```

Thank you for your help.

EDIT : I tried without idplayer and I have the same error.

EDIT 2 : Could it be because I have some null values in my player entity ? But I don't really know what they are (these are not values that are in my entity class). Here is what dump() show for my player before I do the query :

```
Player {#496 ▼
  #id: 13
  -pseudo: "jean3"
  #email: "cava@gmail.com"
  #password: "0f22f0605b46b21c396d3aebe9b787bee7bbd3b31ca3548dfa5a8a6c2ec090de"
  -dateLog: DateTime {#493 ▶}
  -characters: PersistentCollection {#523 ▶}
  -messages: PersistentCollection {#549 ▶}
  #salt: "380012397590c3fc630f46"
  #_entityName: null
  #_em: null
  #_class: null
}
```

The last 3 parameters are null, but like I said I didn't created these myself

Comment: in fact everything seems ok, try to execute that query directly in some sql gui or mysql console and see what it's saying.

Comment: I don't see why you use `private` as manytoOne relationship attribute, and also IdPlayer as integere (with same join column). `player is enough`. You can have a setPlayer directly

Comment: I also have the same error when I try this query in phpmyadmin

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had a syntax error because I have a column called "date", and it is a reserved word in SQL ! So I just renamed my column and it works.

EDIT : Same for from AND type !...